# Передача данных из jsp в сервлет и на другой jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Имеется файл cabinetList.jsp, из него нужно взять параметр idCabinet./n
и перенаправить в другой documentList.jsp чтобы выводились документы которые находятся в определенном Cabinet с со своим idCabinet после нажатия кнопки Access.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="lifecycle/js/cabinetJS.js"></script>
<title>Cabinets</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You are logged in as <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></p>



<a href="DocumentList">Document List</a>



    <form  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
    <c:if test="${(not empty name) && (name1=='name1')}">
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return setCabinet(this);">
    <p>${answer}</p>
    <c:remove var="answer" scope="session" /> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
            <th>Cabinet ID</th>
            <th>Cabinet Name</th>
            <th>Owner Name</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${cabList}" var="cab">
        <tr>
            <td><label><input type="radio" name="cabinet" onclick="setDocumentButton(this);" value="${cab.idCabinet}" > ${cab.idCabinet}</label></td>
            <td>${cab.nameCabinet}</td>
            <td>${cab.nameOwner}</td>
            <td>${cab.dateStorage}</td>
        </tr>   
    </c:forEach>

    <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <table class="buttons"
                    style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border: none !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" disabled onclick="page='CabinetList'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" disabled onclick="page='CabinetDelete'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" onclick="page='CabinetList'" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Access" name="access" disabled onclick="page='DocumentList'" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </form> 
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${(empty name) || (name1!='name1')}">
  <%
    response.sendRedirect("UserLogin");
  %>
  </c:if>
```

Вот Сервлет CabinetList

```
package com.jmd.cabinet.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;

 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

 import com.jmd.cabinet.data.Cabinet;
 import com.jmd.cabinet.services.CabinetService;
import com.jmd.util.ServiceException;
import com.jmd.util.web.GenericServlet;

@WebServlet("/CabinetList")
public class CabinetList extends GenericServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private CabinetService cabservices = null;



public void init() {
    super.init();
    if (connector != null) {
        cabservices = new CabinetService(connector);

    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String view;
    try {
        view = populateView(request);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(view);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     if(request.getParameter("edit")!=null){

            List<Cabinet> cabUpdateList;
            cabUpdateList = cabservices.getCabinetsById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cabinet")));
            request.setAttribute("cabUpdateList", cabUpdateList);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/cabinet/createCabinet.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        }else if(request.getParameter("add")!=null){
            String view;
            try {
                view = populateCreateJsp(request);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(view);
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if(request.getParameter("cancel")!=null){
            doGet(request,response);
        }else if(request.getParameter("access")!=null){
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("idCabinet", "idCabinet");
         response.sendRedirect("DocumentList");
        }
}

private String populateView(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws ServiceException {
    if (cabservices == null) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Service not initialised");
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp";
    }

    List<Cabinet> cabList;
    cabList = cabservices.getCabinets();
    request.setAttribute("cabList", cabList);
    return "/WEB-INF/jsp/cabinet/cabinetList.jsp";
}
private String populateCreateJsp(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException {
    if (cabservices == null) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Service not initialised");
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp";
    }
    return "/WEB-INF/jsp/cabinet/createCabinet.jsp";
}

}
```

Вот Второй сервлет от DocumentList

```
package com.jmd.document.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import com.jmd.util.ServiceException;
import com.jmd.document.services.DocumentService;
import com.jmd.util.web.GenericServlet;

import com.jmd.document.data.Document;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

@WebServlet("/DocumentList")
public class DocumentList extends GenericServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DocumentService documentService = null;

public void init(){
    super.init();
    if(connector != null){
        documentService = new DocumentService(connector);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String view;
    try{
        view = populateView(request);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(view);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServiceException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    if (request.getParameter("edit")!=null){
        List<Document> docUpdateList;
        docUpdateList = documentService.getDocumentsById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("document")));
        request.setAttribute("docUpdateList", docUpdateList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/document/createDocument.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }else if(request.getParameter("add")!=null){
        String view;
        try {
            view = populateCreateJsp(request);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(view);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(request.getParameter("create")!=null){
        createDocument(request, response);
    }
    else if(request.getParameter("delete")!=null){
        deleteDocument(request, response);
    }else if(request.getParameter("extend")!=null){
        List<Document> docUpdateList;
        docUpdateList = documentService.getDocumentsById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Document")));
        request.setAttribute("docUpdateList", docUpdateList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/centraldepot/supliedocument.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }else if(request.getParameter("cancel")!=null){
        doGet(request,response);
    }
}

private void createDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Document document = new Document();
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    document.setNameDocument(request.getParameter("nameDocument"));
    document.setTipDocument(request.getParameter("tipDocument"));
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        if (filePart != null){
            document.setTipContent(filePart.getContentType());
            document.setSizeContent((int) filePart.getSize());
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }

    document.setAuthor(request.getParameter("author"));
    document.setKeyword(request.getParameter("keyword")) ;


    documentService.insertDocuments(document);
    response.sendRedirect("DocumentList");
}

private void deleteDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    documentService.removeDocuments(Integer.parseInt(request
            .getParameter("document")));
    response.sendRedirect("DocumentList");
}

    private String populateView(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException {
        if (documentService == null) {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Service not initialised");
            return "/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp";
        }

        List<Document> docList;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.getAttribute("idCabinet");
        docList = documentService.getDocuments();
        request.setAttribute("docList", docList);
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/document/documentList.jsp";

    }
    private String populateCreateJsp(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException {
        if (documentService == null) {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Service not initialised");
            return "/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp";
        }
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/document/createDocument.jsp";
    }

}
```

documentList.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="lifecycle/js/documentJS.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You chose <%=session.getAttribute("idCabinet")%></p>
    <form  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
    <c:if test="${(not empty name) && (name1=='name1')}">
    <form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return setDocument(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="idCabinet" value="" />
    <p>${answer}</p>
    <c:remove var="answer" scope="session" /> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
            <th>Document ID</th>
            <th>Document Name</th>
            <th>Tip Document</th>
            <th>Tip Continut</th>
            <th>Dimensiune Continut</th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${docList}" var="doc">
        <tr>

            <td><label><input type="radio" name="document" onclick="setDocumentButton(this);" value="${doc.idDocument}" > ${doc.idDocument}</label></td>
            <td>${doc.nameDocument}</td>
            <td>${doc.tipDocument}</td>
            <td>${doc.tipContent}</td>
            <td>${doc.sizeContent}</td>
        </tr>   
    </c:forEach>
```

<%response.sendRedirect("UserLogin");%>

Comment: Что за функции javascript `setDocumentButton()`, `setCabinet()`, переменная `page`?

Comment: вот это не кажется странным `session.setAttribute("idCabinet", "idCabinet");`?

Comment: Какой вопрос? Непонятна суть вопроса. В чем состоит ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно добавить необходимый вам атрибут в сессию и перейти action-ом или ссылкой на другую страницу. 
Вы сделали почти то, что нужно

```
session.setAttribute("idCabinet", "idCabinet");
```

Только вместе второго "idCabinet" нужно было указать значение, а не строку.

Comment: так а мне нужно чтобы значение вставлялось исходя из выбранного id, и до меня не доходит как это осуществить